# Cassandra update statement in C#

Tags: c#, cassandra, cql

When I try to update the data in my Cassandra table I get the following error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Cassandra.InvalidQueryException' occurred in Cassandra.dll
>
> Additional information: Slice restrictions are not supported on the clustering columns in UPDATE statements

This is my code that does the actual updating:

```
public void updateMeters(List<model> update)
    {
        Connect();
        // List<int> blabla 
        var statement = session.Prepare("UPDATE csvmeter SET meterid=? where MeterName=? and timeStamp<?");
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var item in update)
        {
            var bind = statement.Bind(update.Select(x => x.MeterId), update.Select(x => x.MeterNumber), DateTime.Now);
            var resultSetFuture = session.ExecuteAsync(bind);
            tasks.Add(resultSetFuture);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        CloseConnection();
    }
```

I know almost for sure the problem occurs at the `and Timestamp<?` because its part of my primary key.

This is my database model:

```
Create table csvmeter (
meterName    varchar,
timeStamp    timestamp,
Value        double,
meterID      int,
PRIMARY KEY(meterName, timeStamp));
```

I want to update meterID based on the Metername. This metername is not distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements all the primary key columns must be restricted and the only allowed restrictions are:

- the single-column = on any partition key or clustering columns
- the single-column IN restriction on the last partition key column

[CASSANDRA-6237](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6237) addresses part of those limitations in Cassandra 3.0.

See this post at DataStax dev blog for more info: [A deep look at the CQL WHERE clause](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause).